# Notation Question From Ribet's "From the Taniyama-Shimura Conjecture to Fermat’s Last Theorem"

Tags: number-theory, elliptic-curves, modular-forms

What is $J$ on page 19 (...and their analogues $T_n \in \operatorname{End}(J)$ which were introduced by Shimura...)? This object is referenced constantly throughout the paper, but never defined, as far as I can tell (by going through every instance of the letter $J$ found in the entire paper up until and shortly after this point).

Comment: I don't understand the vote to close.

Comment: This is rather on p. 134 of the published version (http://www.numdam.org/item?id=AFST_1990_5_11_1_116_0)

Comment: I was using: chrome-extension://efaidnbmnnnibpcajpcglclefindmkaj/https://math.berkeley.edu/~ribet/Articles/toulousela.pdf and I do not see any difference (except for the page numbering) between the two versions.

Comment: I’m not sure, but it looks like $J$ is $\mathrm{Pic}^o(C)$ (they’re abelian varieties, one is noted for a Jacobian and the other one is a Jacobian, $J$ is supposed to “be like” a modular Jacobian but isn’t, they have the same “purely multiplicative reduction” at $p$, they’re both stated to contain some flavor of dual of $Y$…).

Comment: Ok, this makes sense. As I was reading the paper I just said to myself "something to do with C probably because otherwise C seems to play no role here."